# Pug template inheritance with different paths (and depths)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am running into the problem that I have a 'main layout' which gets extended by other pug files, defining the layout for specific sites.

Example:
`main.pug`

Path: /we [`we.pug` extends `main.pug`]

However, when I start to have routes like `/we/are/nice/because` which are just specifications of `/we` and I would like to use the same `main.pug`, I run into the problem that by the way NodeJS renders the pug files, the src/href paths of JS and CSS includes are off (eg: `https://localhost:3001/we/are/nice/script.js` won't be found because it is supposed to be at `localhost:3001/script.js`)

Is there a simple way to fix this issue, or do I need specific `main.pug` files for all path-depths ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pointing to absolute paths? So `/script.js`, instead of `script.js`, in an link/href attribute. This assumes, of course, that the files are served from a server like NodeJS (not by the filesystem).